# C# заполнение <input> html

Tags: c#, html, winforms

Решил написать бота для подбора Track-номеров на сайте почты.
В интернете нашел статью

Мне нужно сделать так что б при загрузки формы заполнилось поле "Отслеживание" трэк номером, вот что у меня получилось:

Вот код:

```
private void TestTrackNumbers(string Track)
    {
        HtmlElement body = wb.Document.Body;

        HtmlElementCollection inputArray = 
        body.GetElementsByTagName("input");
        HtmlElement input = inputArray[0];
        input.SetAttribute("value", Track);
    }
```

Помогите сделать так что бы не было фоногого текста, **OpenQA не предлагать**.

Спасибо

Comment: Просить помощь во взломе сайта - по моему это уже не совсем корректно.

Comment: Подбор/перебор 13-значного числа, даже при 100запросах/сек займёт более 1 млн дней. Задача смысла не имеет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала следует посмотреть текущую логику работы плейсхолдера при вводе значения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно заметить, `div.input__placeholder` удаляется при вводе значения. Проделайте анологичную операцию и вы:

```
var divs = body.GetElementsByTagName("div");
foreach (HtmlElement div in body.GetElementsByTagName("div"))
{
    if (div.GetAttribute("className").Contains("input__placeholder"))
    {
        div.OuterHtml = "";
    }
}
```